# Copy assignment implementation of a class which has a member object of that class.(c++)

Tags: c++

I am a new computing science student and not very experienced in c++. I've been googling for hours, and did not come across a solution(to be honest, i couldn't even find a good statement to search). Basically what i'm trying to learn here is how to implement a copy operator for a case like:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class foo
{
    foo* parentObject;
    std::vector<foo*> childObjects;
    char a;
    int *b;
public:
    foo(char a, int* b) : a(a), b(b) {};
    foo();
    foo& operator =(const foo& other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = new int(*other.b);
        //parentobject???
        //pretty sure i can figure childObjects if i can manageparentObject,
        //but just in case there are some special stuff wanted to include.
        return *this;
    }
    friend void getElements(std::string fpath);
};
```

To go deeper, i want to read objects of the same type that are in a tree-like hierarchy(sort of like XML) from a formatted text file and have only one instance of the object i read in the memory(lets assume thats what getElements does), and the rest are pointers to those objects(we can think of this as how shortcuts work). That is because, i thought that would be the most efficient method since there can be a lot of objects, please correct me if i'm wrong.

But i also want to keep track of the structure so i decided to go with this parent/child design(again could be a bad choice, feel free to enlighten me). Because of the reading method i used(from parent to children), even though i can find a way to initialize parentObject, i can't simply initialize childObjects. Therefore i can't use a 'new constructor()' assignment(or maybe i can but i just don't know that i can).

If the reason behind my need of (**shallow**)copy operator is unclear, since i didn't initialize parentObject or childObjects, i need to assign them later on while reading the text document(it really feels like i shouldn't need one but i think i do.).

My actual code is really hard to read; since this is a project just to get better at c++, i didn't give importance to coding style) and it is longer so i created a simpler version. I really appreciate any comment so feel free to write one.

Edit: I couldn't even copy paste properly(initialization of b).
Edit: Clearence.

Comment: `b(b)` in your member initialization list had better flag a warning from your compiler; you're initializing `int*` with `int`. Beyond that, understanding the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) better is probably warranted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677394/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-of-this-constructor

Comment: I think you still didn't state the problem clear. do you want  a deep copy or just shallow copy?

Comment: Shallow copy. I want both new copy and old pointer to point at the same object/memory location.

Comment: @user3402183: I think what you actually want is to disallow copies, and to only allow moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into the logical problems of having an XML node copy itself. There is really no clear and intuitive way to go about copying an XML node that's part of a tree. And a rule of thumb in C++ is: if an `operator` doesn't act intuitively, make it a named function instead.  In your case, I would make a `foo& assign_from_content(foo&)` function that acts like a copy assignment, and a `static foo construct_from_content(foo&)` that acts like a copy constructor, that only copies the content.

Now what to do with the copy constructor and copy assignment operators? `delete` them.  And use move construction and move assignment instead.

```
foo& operator =(const foo& other)=delete;
foo& operator =(foo&& other) noexcept=delete;
{
    disconnect_from_tree();

    a = other.a;
    delete b;
    b = other.b;
    other.b = null;

    take_place_in_tree(other);       
    return *this;
}

//These are untested, they probably don't compile and have logical errors
void disconnect_from_tree() noexcept {
    if (parentObject) {
        auto it = std::find(parentObject->childObjects.begin(), 
                            parentObject->childObjects.end(), 
                            this);
        if(it != parentObject->childObjects.end())
            parentObject->childObjects.erase(it);
    }
    for(foo* child : childObjects)
        child->parentObject = nullptr;
    childObjects.clear();
}

//These are untested, they probably don't compile and have logical errors
void take_place_in_tree(foo& other) noexcept {
    childObjects = std::move(other.childObjects);
    parentObject = other.parentObject;     
    other.disconnect_from_tree();
    for(foo* child : childObjects)
        child->parentObject = this;  
    if (parentObject) {
        auto it = std::find(parentObject->childObjects.begin(), 
                            parentObject->childObjects.end(), 
                            this);
        if(it != parentObject->childObjects.end())
            parentObject->childObjects.erase(it);
        parentObject->childObjects.push_back(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually thought about this but it was rather unclear to me if or how i could implement it. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an object that has member variables to define a tree of the objects, copy constructor or copy assignment operator will not be sufficient to deal with all cases. You may want to:

1. Copy just the contents of a node in the tree (`a`, and `b` in your case).
2. Copy one layer of parents and children.
3. Copy `N` layers of parents and children.
4. Copy `N1` layers of parents and and `N2` layers of children.
5. Copy the entire tree.

(1) above can be handled by a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator. For the rest, it's better to have `extern` functions that traverse the tree and make a copy of the right portion of the tree.

Comment: I see, but i still don't understand how i would assign a value to the pointer. Does that mean i don't need to overload 'operator=' to execute:
    *myobject.parentObject = otherObject;

Comment: Sorry i hit enter and it posted the comment, i didn't know comments did that.

Comment: @user3402183, that seems to me to be the best you can do. Just copy `a` and `*b`, and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Oh, i only tried to implement one (edit:) that copies those layers  because i thought i had to... But i'm happy i did so i could learn these things.

Comment: @user3402183, that's the right thing to do. Using the compiler generated copy constructor and copy assignment operator will be a problem for a `struct` like yours.